# Mediawiki-like editor for custom site?

Tags: mediawiki

I was searching the web for a long time but couldn't find any answer... Is there any text editor simliar to Mediawiki's / Wikipedia's which you can integrate to a html  (just like it works with tinyMce)? I really like the markup and way creating a new page works in mediawiki.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a CMS that supports simple markup like **markdown** or **RestructuredText**. Maybe you like one of these? http://www.queness.com/post/14579/6-lightweight-flexible-php-cms

If you want to use (full) MediaWiki syntax, you'll have to use MediaWiki. MediaWiki's syntax is ill-designed, and the parser hopelessly tangled with the rest of the software. It's a nice example of what **not** to do if you want a re-usable parser or [alternative parser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) implementations.

Comment: I am currently developing my own cms, so I have to implement an editor like that on my own. I was hoping there was an alternative for tinyMCE with an user interface similar to wikipedia...